# Save Selected JTable Rows and Show them in another JTable (in another JFrame)

Tags: java, swing, object, arraylist, jtable

I have a table with some data. I want to select a couple of rows which I want to monitor (I will then display these rows in a new `JFrame` with its own table) - let's call this monitored records.

I have this piece of code I found that does this exactly, but it creates the new table with the same number of rows as the original table. It however does show the new selected rows successfully but it populates the new table from the bottom going up.

For instance my original table has 10 rows, I select 3, the new table will have 10 rows in total, but only 8, 9 and 10 are populated with the selected data and rows 1 to 7 just have empty cells.

How do I make it only show the selected data and not the empty rows?

```
public void exportSelectedRows(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        TableModel tableModel = patientTable.getModel();
        int[] index = patientTable.getSelectedRows();
        Object[] row = new Object[10]; //problem is here that object has size 10 hence the 10 rows?
        monitoredPatients = new MonitoredPatients();
        monitoredPatients.monitoredPatientsTable = new JTable(row.length, columnNames.length);
        DefaultTableModel defaultTableModel = (DefaultTableModel) monitoredPatients.monitoredPatientsTable.getModel();
        for (int value : index) {
            row[0] = tableModel.getValueAt(value, 0);
            row[1] = tableModel.getValueAt(value, 1);
            row[2] = tableModel.getValueAt(value, 2);
            row[3] = tableModel.getValueAt(value, 3);
            row[4] = tableModel.getValueAt(value, 4);
            row[5] = tableModel.getValueAt(value, 5);
            defaultTableModel.addRow(row);
        }
        monitoredPatients.add(new JScrollPane(monitoredPatients.monitoredPatientsTable));
    }
```

I expect the new table to only show the selected records with no empty rows.

Comment: 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

row = new Object[10]; //problem is here that object has size 10 hence the 10 rows?
..
monitoredPatients.monitoredPatientsTable = new JTable(row.length, columnNames.length);

Well you have a couple of problems:

1. Why would you create the row Array with a value of 10? The row array represents the data for each row. You only copy 6 columns of data, so the size of the array should only be 6.
2. The value for the number of rows should be 0, since you are starting with an empty DefaulotTableModel. You then use the `addRow(...)` method to add a new row of data. This makes the size of your TableModel dynamic.

So the code should be:

```
monitoredPatients.monitoredPatientsTable = new JTable(0, columnNames.length);
```

Or better yet, why don't you create the TableModel with the array containing the name of the columns? I'm sure you don't want to see "A, B, C, D, E, F", which will be the default if you just specify the number of columns. Read the DefaultTableModel API for the appropriate constructor to use.

Comment: Thanks a ton. Everything works as I want it to now. I already had a string array `columnNames` . So I just had to call `setColumnIdentifiers()` on `defaultTableModel`

Comment: `I already had a string array columnNames ...` - then you can use the constructor that accepts the array as the column names and the number of row (which wold be 0). That is why I suggested you read the API to look at the various constructors.